# Can OCD (osteochondral defect)/OCL patients return to sports/athletic activities with proper rehabilitation?

Tags: orthopedics, sports, knee

[This](https://www.jospt.org/doi/pdf/10.2519/jospt.2006.2303) study examines OCD and OCL treatment options and the rehabilitation process. The author notes:

> Often our medical advice to the patient with OA is to ‘‘avoid
> performing weight-bearing exercise.’’ Although the recommendation
> appears logical, it is not the most effective advice or best practice
> for the young athletic individual with a focal articular cartilage
> lesion. This type of patient is often highly motivated and desires an
> active lifestyle with exercise. We, as health care providers in the
> 21st century, must develop treatment strategies that effectively
> address and treat the patients’ unique injuries and facilitate return
> to desired activities.

Does current literature support returning athletes with OCL, OCD to their respective sports?

The author also notes that supplementing glucosamine and chondroitin may have positive effects on rehabilitation outcomes, but that these drugs seemingly work better when used together. The author also describes their use as "controversial" with the science not being fully understood on the mechanism of action.

Does the literature show positive effects from these supplements in patients returning from OCD/OCL injuries? In what capacity (if any) can these supplements expedite the process of recovery?

Comment: I attempted to make this question more objective. I deleted requests for personal experience and deleted the previous post. Any advice on making this more objective to meet the question standards would be appreciated.